# How to select range 160 to 255 in regex

Tags: regex

I have tried this way to find the result, But it's also select 10 to 19.

```
([1][6-9]?[0-9])|([2][0-4][0-9])|(25[0-5])
```

So please help how to select without 10 to 19.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `?` from `[6-9]` in the first group. `?` quantifier will make the character class `[6-9]` appear zero or once.

> [The question mark makes the preceding token in the regular expression optional.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html)

```
([1][6-9][0-9])|([2][0-4][0-9])|(25[0-5])
```

You can also group them together as

[`([1][6-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])`](https://www.regex101.com/r/hJSeLC/1)

Answer (score 1):

here is an answer with less parentheses and brackets:
`1[6-9][0-9]|2([0-4][0-9]|5[0-5])`